# Automount when changing USB floppy

Tags: 16.04, usb, mount, automount, floppy

When changing the floppy in my usb floppy drive /dev/sdb which is mounted to /home/user/floppy it won't change the contents of my mount directory until I click the floppy icon in the left taskbar or unmount and remount manually.

How can I change this behaviour so my mount directory always shows the floppy content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most floppy disk drives do not detect a media change. Some try to emulate this behaviour by watching for a signal change on the write protection photoelectric sensor, but this would not work in all cases.

Floppy disc drives that can detect media changes normally do have an electrical ejection system and no mechanical button to do so. These systems can do the trick you like to have but these are rare. And, well, you would be clicking "unmount" anyway, the difference would be the disc being ejected ;)

BTW: it is no good idea to manually eject the floppy from the drive before logically unmounting it in the operation system as there might be unwritten buffers, software might have open files etc.

Comment: Thank you, I was expecting this. I wonder how DOS software handled this as there occured frequent media changes for file transfer. But I guess they just directly accessed the drive which isnt possible here...

Comment: (Early) DOS used floppy disks without any buffering. So any filesystem changes would have been written to disk synchronously. The risk of having a disc removed from drive was still there but while there was write access, the drive showed the "active" lamp to the user signaling to keep his hands off ;)

BTW: In the DOS "precurser" CP/M you had to sync the disk by pressing  CTRL-Z or something like that - don't really remember the key combination exactly.

First Macintosh computers solved this hy having no eject button but an electrical ejection system initiated by the OS.

Comment: Just to add on to this: I was able to find a workaround using [autofs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs) which unmounts the drive automatically after a specified idle time (e.g. 5 seconds) and remounts it automatically when accessing the mount point, so I can switch floppies nearly fearless :)